# Resetting gone wrong

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, ip, ipv6

I have reset my linksys router, and now my internet is horribly slow.
please check details from command prompt below and tell me what's wrong. Thanks.

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Think>ipconfig /all
>
> Windows IP Configuration
>
> Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Think-PC    Primary Dns Suffix 
>   . . . . . . . :    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Peer-Peer    IP
>   Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . .
>   . : No    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Home
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
>   . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter    Physical Address. . . .
>   . . . . . : 08-3E-8E-A6-74-09    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Yes    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
>   . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
>   00-FF-8D-03-85-AB    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
>   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home    Description . . . . . .
>   . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter    Physical Address. . .
>   . . . . . . : 08-3E-8E-A6-74-09    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Yes    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    Link-local IPv6
>   Address . . . . . : fe80::6d26:5dca:5dec:3e11%12(Preferred)    IPv4
>   Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100(Preferred)    Subnet Mask
>   . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . .
>   . . : 20 December 2013 07:19:53    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . :
>   21 December 2013 07:19:53    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
>   192.168.1.1    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 352861838    DHCPv6 Client DUID. .
>   . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-E7-A5-EE-B8-88-E3-E8-81-D6
>
> DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 208.67.222.222
>                                          192.168.1.1    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
>
> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home    Description . . . . . . .
>   . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller    Physical Address. . .
>   . . . . . . : B8-88-E3-E8-81-D6    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Yes    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
>   . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface    Physical Address. . . . .
>   . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . .
>   : No    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    IPv6 Address. . . .
>   . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:817:129f:3f57:fe9b(Prefe rred)
>   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . :
>   fe80::817:129f:3f57:fe9b%21(Preferred)    Default Gateway . . . . . .
>   . . . : ::    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
>
> Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
>   . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
>   00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap.Home:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home    Description . . . . . .
>   . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2    Physical Address. . . . . .
>   . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
>   No    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    Link-local IPv6
>   Address . . . . . : fe80::5efe:192.168.1.100%24(Preferred)    Default
>   Gateway . . . . . . . . . :    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   208.67.222.222
>                                          192.168.1.1    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{8D0385AB-841D-4FA3-A3AB-08FA1E6B0EE4}:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
>   . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
>   00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{2960ADF4-79DD-44C8-8794-6033DE9AA0CB}:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
>   . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
>   00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> C:\Users\Think>
>
> C:\Users\Think>ipconfig /all

Comment: How long has this been happening for? It seems unlikely that a setting of your router is making your internet slow, I'd bet that you're probably just having some transient issue with your internet that happens to have occurred after you reset it.

Answer (score 2):

You have Teredo enabled, but your system hasn't correctly identified your public IPv4 address. This is due to a double NAT situation (you are behind two home routers both doing NAT, or you have one router and your ISP is also NATting your connection); Teredo addresses encode what should be the public IPv4 address, but [yours](https://ip.addr.space/2001:0:9d38:6abd:817:129f:3f57:fe9b) encodes the address 192.168.1.100, a private address. This only happens in a double NAT setup.

Since this gives you a mostly-nonfunctional or completely broken IPv6 address, and IPv6 is preferred to IPv4, this will slow down your connectivity to any IPv6 enabled web site (Google, Facebook, many others).

I always recommend disabling Teredo, ISATAP and 6to4, all of which are IPv6 transition technologies with various pitfalls, unless you actually intend to use them.

Open an elevated command prompt by right-clicking the Command Prompt icon and selecting Run as Administrator, and enter the following commands:

```
netsh int ipv6 isatap set state disabled
netsh int ipv6 6to4 set state disabled
netsh int teredo set state disabled
```

Each should return `The command completed successfully.`

Then restart your computer.