# Wireless, IPv6: no network, unidentified netword at random

Tags: windows-7, networking, ipv6

I have been reading other threads and trying suggested steps but nothing seems to work for me.
50% of time the internet works fine, sometimes it slows down sometimes there is no connection at all.
The most common problem seems to be "IPv6 connectivity: no network access"
sometimes: IPv4 displays the same message
sometimes it says "unidentified network" or "limited network access".

I've copied my computer's specs, if that is of any use. It would be great if sb would be able to help me with that.

**I posted third ipconfig log for when there is absolutely no connection (at the bottom)**

```
OS Name                 Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium
Version                 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer         Microsoft Corporation
System Name             WIKTOR-LAPTOP
System Manufacturer     Acer
System Model            Aspire 5742
System Type             x64-based PC
Processor               Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 380  @ 2.53GHz, 2533 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date       Acer V1.16, 2011-02-16
SMBIOS Version          2.6
Windows Directory       C:\Windows
System Directory        C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device             \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Locale                  United Kingdom
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.1.7601.17514"
User Name               Wiktor-laptop\Wiktor
Time Zone               GMT Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 4,00 GB
Total Physical Memory           3,68 GB
Available Physical Memory       1,65 GB
Total Virtual Memory            7,35 GB
Available Virtual Memory        4,91 GB
Page File Space                 3,68 GB
Page File                       C:\pagefile.sys
```

---

`ipconfig /all` (when all running ok):

```
Windows IP Configuration  

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Wiktor-laptop  
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :   
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid  
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 88-9F-FA-1B-5B-2A  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:  

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 88-9F-FA-1B-5B-2A  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ed8b:5247:82f0:6c5e%12(Preferred)   
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.4(Preferred)   
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 4 lutego 2014 01:38:01  
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 5 lutego 2014 08:24:34  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1  
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1  
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 193503226  
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-0B-42-32-1C-75-08-DF-2D-E4  
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 194.168.4.100  
                                       194.168.8.100  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled  

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-75-08-DF-2D-E4  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9DAF301C-0E09-4554-B368-281B86C54CA1}:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C26A5194-2613-4665-AC9F-5A319F64A1B2}:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

`ipconfig /all` (when the IPv6 shows "no internet access" and there is no actual internet   access or it's breaking up) [unfortunately, I can't show you ipconfig from when it doesnt fing the network ast all as it happens only every few days]

```
Windows IP Configuration  

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Wiktor-laptop  
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :   
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid  
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 88-9F-FA-1B-5B-2A  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:  

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 88-9F-FA-1B-5B-2A  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ed8b:5247:82f0:6c5e%12(Preferred)   
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.4(Preferred)   
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 4 lutego 2014 19:38:02  
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 5 lutego 2014 19:51:34  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1  
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1  
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 193503226  
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-0B-42-32-1C-75-08-DF-2D-E4  
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 194.168.4.100  
                                       194.168.8.100  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled  

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-75-08-DF-2D-E4  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9DAF301C-0E09-4554-B368-281B86C54CA1}:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C26A5194-2613-4665-AC9F-5A319F64A1B2}:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I copied ip config from when there is no internet at all and there is no IPv4 or 6 connectivity. I can't spot any differences

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Wiktor-laptop  
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :   
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid  
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 88-9F-FA-1B-5B-2A  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:  

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 88-9F-FA-1B-5B-2A  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ed8b:5247:82f0:6c5e%12(Preferred)   
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.4(Preferred)   
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 15 lutego 2014 09:05:55  
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 16 lutego 2014 12:26:43  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1  
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1  
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 193503226  
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-0B-42-32-1C-75-08-DF-2D-E4  
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 194.168.4.100  
                                       194.168.8.100  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled  

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-75-08-DF-2D-E4  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9DAF301C-0E09-4554-B368-281B86C54CA1}:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C26A5194-2613-4665-AC9F-5A319F64A1B2}:  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected  
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Are you connected to the network via a wired connection or WiFi? Do your other devices (i.e. phone) have any problems connecting to the same network?

Comment: I am connected via wifi. My phones and older laptop work totally fine with this wifi.

Comment: Run `ipconfig /all` when the connection is working fine, and save the output. Run it _again_ when the connection is completely broken, and save the output again. Post them both here as an addition to your question. (Not just as a comment; only edits will bump your post.)

Comment: I doesn't show any changes i suppose. I ran it again when there was no inernet at all and it was the same.

Comment: You don't seem to have IPv6 connectivity from your ISP at all, so that is probably a red herring. Just in case, you can try [disabling Teredo, ISATAP and 6to4](http://superuser.com/a/691421/144961) as those can cause a variety of weird issues.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it didn't help. Btw. would a usb adapter solve the problem? Would it be enough to buy this: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Edimax-EW-7811UN-150Mbps-Wireless-Adapter/dp/B003MTTJOY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1392567335&sr=8-1&keywords=usb+wifi+adapter